# how to group custom post type posts by custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, wp-query

I would really appreciate if you could help me :) I'm very stuck and don't know how to proceed.

I have a custom post type called `event` and 2 custom taxonomies registered for it:

1. `event_type` with tag-like functionality (ex. of event type: yoga, voice work)
2. `event_location` with category-like functionality (ex of event location: uk->brighton, london; europe->paris).

There are pages on the website like `Yoga -> Upcoming events`; `Voice work -> Upcoming workshops`. Depending on which page we are on I'd like to display appropriate events. For example, if we're on page `Yoga -> Upcoming events` I'd like to display all `event` custom posts with `event_type` being yoga and then group the results by `event_location` taxonomy terms. For example, list all yoga events for UK, Brighton then UK, London and then Europe, Paris and so on.

What I currently do in a template is the following:

1. I get the slug of the current page and its ancestors.
2. I get slugs of all terms in the `event_type` taxonomy, that have some events associated with them.
3. I determine which event types to display, by intersecting previously gathered values.
4. Then I construct a WP_Query to get `event` posts with determined `event_type` taxonomy terms.

This seems to work. However, results came back unordered and I would like them to be ordered by `event_location` taxonomy terms. For example:

- UK

  - Brighton

    - Event 1
    - Event 2
  - London

    - Event 3
- Europe

  - Paris

    - Event 4

I would also like to display only non-expired `event` posts and order them by `event_date`. The `event_date` value is stored as meta value along with the rest of `event` post details under a single meta_key.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
    //pull in the appropriate events depending on the page type: yoga/voice work
    /* get the ancestors and current page slugs */
    // collect ancestor pages
    $relations = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    // add current post to pages
    array_push($relations, $post->ID);
    // get pages slugs
    $relations_slugs = array();
    foreach($relations as $page_ID){
        $page = get_page($page_ID);
        array_push($relations_slugs, $page->post_name);
    }

    /* get the term slugs (non-empty) for event_type taxonomy */
    //get the event_type taxonomy values
    $event_types = get_terms( 'event_type', 'hide_empty=true' );
    $event_types_slugs = array();
    foreach($event_types as $event_type){
        array_push($event_types_slugs, $event_type->slug);
    }

    /* find what event_type to display on the current page */
    $page_event_types = array_intersect($relations_slugs, $event_types_slugs);
    $page_event_types_string = implode(",",$page_event_types);

    /* find the events of the event_type to display on the current page */
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $page_event_types_string
            )
        )
    );
    $temp = $wp_query; //assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    /* run the loop to output the event's details */
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'event-details' );
```

I'm not great at constructing SQL statements. I would really appreciate if you could help me.
Thank you very much!!!

**EDIT**

I have significantly simplified the functionality (as I got quite confused and lost in the original one). Please see my answer.

Thanks to @Bainternet for taking the time and trying to help me out!

Comment: Try taking a look at the posts_groupby filter. Here's a related WPXchg link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/query-on-custom-field-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a bit confused with this one. At the end I've decided not to group the events by `event_location` category and simplify the functionality.

What I have done instead is the following:

1. I detect what `event_type` events to display by looking at a URL. Then I display all the events of that `event_type` and order them by `event_date` ASC - the ones that coming soon appear first. Here the URL is of format `/events?type=event_type`
2. I present a sidebar with all the `event_location` category terms. A user can see all events in a specific location by clicking on the links. The URL in this case has the following format: `/events?location=event_location`. Events of all types but for that specific location are displayed ordered ASC (the ones that coming soon appear first).

Then in my custom query I include `'tax_query'`. For example, for the `event_location` taxonomy something like:

```
$wp_query['tax_query'] = array('taxonomy' => 'event_location',
                               'field' => 'slug',
                               'terms' => $_GET['location']
                              )
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

try using this fancy function that group the posts by term id that [Scribu and Mike created](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html):

```
function event_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && 'event_location' == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {

        $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = 'event_location' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

add to your args array `'orderby' => 'event_location'`

and before the query add

```
 add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'event_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

after the query add

```
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'event_clauses');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done as you said, but now query doesn't seem to return anything :S

Comment: @Bainternet I finally managed to see what SQL gets generated in `WP_Query[request]`. Somehow I end up with 2 statements of `JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)` I guess the inner join comes from the previously set query vars. I've deleted one of them and was left with:

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms USING (term_id)  
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (taxonomy = 'event_location' OR taxonomy IS NULL) 
GROUP BY object_id 
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name ORDER BY name ASC) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: @Bainternet, this doesn't return anything either :S

Comment: @Bainternet I think the following line is to blame `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3)`. Here '3' refers to the ID of the `event_type`. I think as soon as SQL selected the records in `event_type` taxonomy, it then can't refer to taxonomy table again to look up for `event_location`. I don't know if self-reference will help here?

Comment: whats the latest code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the filter working as @Bainternet suggested. I've tried building the whole SQL, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong as it doesn't work :S Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

I've hard coded the `event_type` and `event_date` meta key value for the time being.

```
  SELECT posts.*
  FROM wp_posts as posts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta as postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as taxonomy ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms as terms ON taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
  WHERE posts.post_type = 'event' AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND postmeta.meta_key = 'event_date' AND postmeta.meta_value >= '2011-02-02'
  AND terms.slug = 'kirtan' AND taxonomy.taxonomy = 'event_type' AND taxonomy.count > 0
  GROUP BY taxonomy.taxonomy
  ORDER BY terms.slug ASC, postmeta.meta_value ASC
```